# Find duplicate sets of data grouped by foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]

How to check if the above table contains duplicate group of rows based on id. For ex here first two rows of id 1 are matching with the next two rows of id 2 but id 2 also have the third row which is not matching with any two rows of id 1 so it's not duplicate and there could be n no of ids.

I tried it to do with the `group by` and `string_agg` but it didn't work.

Here what I tried:

```
declare @t2 Table( m1 int, m2 int,n varchar(50),n2 varchar(50), id int)

insert into @t2 values(3,1,'c','',1),(2,1,'s','o',1),(2,1,'s','o',2),(3,1,'c','',2),(3,1,'f','',2)
 
if exists( SELECT *
    FROM @t2
    GROUP BY m1,m2,n,n2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
begin
select 'Same.'
end
else 
begin
select 'not found'
end
```

Any help here will be great.
Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Are all "ID" columns of type String? If `n` is not known upfront you most likely will need *dynamic SQL*.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Iptr As per your solution in comment I am posting the same here:

```
declare @t2 table(m1 int, m2 int, n varchar(5), n2 varchar(5), id int);

insert into @t2(m1, m2, n, n2, id)
values
(3, 1, 'c', '', 1),
(2, 1, 's', 'o', 1),
(2, 1, 's', 'o', 2),
(3, 1, 'c', '', 2),
(3, 1, 'f', '', 2),

(3, 1, 'c', '', 4),
(2, 1, 's', 'o', 4),
(3, 1, 'c', '', 10),
(2, 1, 's', 'o', 10),

(3, 1, 'c', '', 5);

--if exists(select a.id from(.. having count(*) = a.idcnt)
select a.id, b.id
from
(
select *, count(*) over (partition by id) as idcnt
from @t2
) as a
join 
(
select *, count(*) over (partition by id) as idcnt
from @t2
) as b on a.id </*>*/ b.id and a.m1 = b.m1 and a.m2 = b.m2 and a.n = b.n and a.n2 = b.n2 and a.idcnt = b.idcnt
group by a.id, b.id, a.idcnt
having count(*) = a.idcnt;


--if exists(select j.j from (..  having count(*) > 1;)
select string_agg(i.id, ',')
from
(
 select distinct id
 from @t2
) as i
cross apply
(
 select r.m1, r.m2, r.n, r.n2
 from @t2 as r
 where r.id = i.id
 order by r.m1, r.m2, r.n, r.n2
 for json path
) as j(j)
group by j.j
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many different ids for each set of rows. If the count is more than one, then there are duplicates. For example:

```
select m1, m2, n, n2, count(distinct id) as cnt
from t
group by m1, m2, n, n2
having count(distinct id) > 1
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working.

Comment: @VARUNSINGH Phrases like "not working" are never useful things to write. Describe exactly how it does not meet your goal. It would certainly help for you to describe what result you want from any query or logic applied to the table.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the correction. I always forget the namespace changes at the `ORDER BY` clause, not yet at `HAVING`.